# Get value of radio button group in route after form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, express, routes

I have a radio button group on my page which is within a form. When the form is submitted, I would like to retrieve the values of the form and save them to my database. It seems that the value for the radio button group is `radiobtngrp: 'on'` but I don't know which one of the radio buttons is on. How do radio buttons work on the submit of a form?

Here is my HTML code for the radio buttons:

```
<label for="q-<%= question.id %>">
    <input id="q-<%= question.id %>-r-i" type="radio" class="form-control" name="radiobtn">
    <img src="/images/a.png">
</label>
```

I have multiple radio buttons which are added through a loop in my ejs file.

My submit button looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-signin btn-yellow" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Now in my route, if I try something like this:

```
console.log(req.body.radiobtn);
```

I see this in the console:

```
radiobtn: 'on'
```

Why is this? And how can I get the actual radio button which was clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Give each radio button in a group both `name` and `value` attributes.

The `name` attribute value is used as the key when submitting a form, with the value of the key taken from the `value` attribute of the selected radio button.

All buttons in the same group share the same `name` attribute value.

Here a quick HTML demo: it's not supposed to do anything except show the query string in the location bar when you hit submit:

```
    <form method="get">
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1">( value 1)<br>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2">( value 2)<br>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="3">( value 3)<br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

---

The default value of the `value` attribute is the string "on".  Hence "on" is sent as the value of the radio group named "radiobtn" when the selected button is missing a value attribute. (Ref. [HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value-default-on))